# Multi-Key Encryption in Java - PGP (BouncyCastle API)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, pgp

Is it possible to encrypt one file with 2 public keys (`pgp`). So it can be decrypted using 2 private keys.

If yes, any lead how this can be achieved?

Thank you, Sandhya Gor.

Comment: Well you can always encrypt entrypted file. Also, what's IIB? Can you tag your question accordingly?

Comment: IIB is Middleware technology. let me tag it properly. thanks